# How to ask user for permission to write file?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Request UAC Elevation c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263918/request-uac-elevation-c-sharp)

In my application, I need to save a file to the programs directory, which requires the administrator privileges. How can I prompt the user to ask for such permission, for example with the usual windows' dialogbox?

Comment: Which "usual windows dialog box" do you mean?

Comment: UAC elevation prompt. You'll need to add a manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't know how to set these rights, you might want to check out this post:

[Set administrative rights C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583501/c-net-acquire-administrator-rights)

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your question correctly, it's how to ask for the permission, so I assume you already understand how to set it. This is a way you could ask for yes / no.

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("The question", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //set the admin rights
} 
else if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: This works if I want the user to agree to something normal but my problem is that I need the user to agree to give my application the permission to write a program in a privilegied path.

Comment: Does not answer